# No setter/field for isCreator found on class

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

When trying to access a Firestore database using Kotlin, the error quoted in the title is thrown. The fields of my model class exactly match the Firestore documents I'm trying to access. Why does Android Studio say there is no setter/field?

There is another field in the same class, which apparently works correctly, no error has been thrown. Even their type is the same, both are Boolean. The only difference is in their names, `isCreator` and `admin` (the working one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with the properties' names. When a property's name starts with "is", one has to explicitly annotate the property's getter the following way:

```
@get:PropertyName("isCreator")
val isCreator: Boolean
```

If your property is mutable (aka `var`), you also have to annotate the setter;

```
@get:PropertyName("isCreator")
@set:PropertyName("isCreator")
var isCreator: Boolean
```

Comment: Thanks! been looking for a few hours for this.